# Проблема добавления на сайт анимации на js

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, анимация

```
var clever = document.getElementById("clever");
  var a = 0;
  function torsion(){
    clever.setAttribute("style", "transform: rotate("+a+"deg)");
    if(a == 360){
        a = 0;
    }
    a++ 
  }
setInterval(torsion,50);
```

При подключении на сайт вот такая вот ошибка в консоли:
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nU5KK.png

Comment: ошибка гласит, что не возможно прочитать setAttribute у null, точно ли на сайте есть элемент с id="clever"?

Comment: <div>
      <img id="clever" src="https://i.ibb.co/YRB1v0X/png-clever.png">
</div>

Comment: @МаксимВоробьев, сначала я тоже подумал, что проблема в том, что я не добавил id="clever", но ответ был неверным

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно в `setInterval` объявить анонимную функцию, внутри которой вызвать `torsion()`:

```js
var clever = document.getElementById("clever");
  var a = 0;
  function torsion(){
    clever.setAttribute("style", "transform: rotate("+a+"deg)");
    if(a == 360){
        a = 0;
    }
    a++
  }
setInterval(function(){torsion()},50);
```

```html
<img id="clever" src="http://quick-trips.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/4444444444444445.jpg" width="300">
```

Но не очень понятно, зачем Вам в принципе js для такой вещи - давно ведь придумали css-анимацию:

```css
@keyframes rotate {
  0 {transform: rotate(0deg)}
  100% {transform: rotate(360deg)}
}
#clever {
  animation: rotate 15s linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<img id="clever" src="http://quick-trips.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/4444444444444445.jpg" width="300">
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. :0